# ScrollView+HorizontalScrollView+Scale is not properly scroll

Tags: java, android

ScrollView and HorizontalScroll cut off some element when scroll vertical or horizontal

here is my xml layout

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
```

and here is dynamicaly adding view to horizontalScrollview

```
TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                TextView cell = new TextView(this);
                cell.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.black_square_border, null));

                cell.setText(("(" + i + ", " + j + ")"));
                cell.setTextSize(10f);
                //  cell.setPadding(6,6,6,6);
                textViewList.add(cell);
                row.addView(cell);
            }
            table.addView(row);
        }

        horizontalScroll.addView(table);
```

Comment: add xml and any screenshot if possible

Comment: try to use TableLayout inside Linear Layout

Comment: @Usama not solve

Comment: I wouldn't recommend putting a scrollView inside another scrollView. try adding android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"

Answer (score 1):

Change your root layout to a NestedScrollView.

Basically, the scroll property of your ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView are overlapping and NestedScrollView was designed to fix this problem. Your layout can look like this:

```
<NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</NestedScrollView>
```

To learn more about NestedScrollViews, check [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView).

Comment: Still cut some content when scroll

Comment: This new issue has to do with your rows. Add `layoutParams` to your rows based on how you want the views to appear.

Comment: Rendering same issue

Comment: Actually i  want to zoom in or zoom out of view with proper both side scroll, if any guide plz mention how is it done, thanks

Comment: Zoom or scroll? Please, note that these are two very different actions.